# How to put javascript in sync manner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried the following way to excute the javascript syncronusly yet i am receiving error..

What I done is firstly i included jquery and jquery ui files dynamically using javascript and after that jquery depends files are present. but at the time of loading the page itexecute the jquery and jquery ui files at last and later part first.

Code Used in single js:

```
(function(){
var script= document.createElement("script");
script.src="jquery.js";
script.type="text/javascript";
var pelement=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[document.getElementsByTagName('script').length-1];  

pelement.insertBefore(script,pelement);

}();


(function(){
var script= document.createElement("script");
script.src="jquery-ui.js";
script.type="text/javascript";
var pelement=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[document.getElementsByTagName('script').length-1];  

pelement.insertBefore(script,pelement);

}();


jquery depend files follows

$(document).ready...
```

Now i recieves error that jquery is undefined..  Even i tried with xmlhttprequest.. but that too failed...

Comment: Your only chance of pausing the execution is to use synchronous XHR (which isn't really recommended). Other than that, your only chance is wrapping the code in a callback or creating a pseudo-jQuery that will collect `ready` events and pass them to the real jQuery when it is finally loaded. The recommended way is to wrap the subsequent execution in a callback.

Comment: Tried XHR method also but that too didn't work... Is there any link how to use callback method

Comment: Well, doesn't the XHR accept an event handler? When the handler is triggered as request completed you execute the remaining code (which has to be inside the handler or store themselves in a global array).

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? From your code, I'd say you could just as easy use two `<script>` tags. Don't see the need for dynamic insertion.

Comment: if jquery is undefined then u might have inserted two files with jwuery definition , make sure if u are using jquery ui then u insert only its js file because it already has a js definition , in that case dont include separate jquery.js file it may conflict the definition and as a result "jquery not defined" u can also use noconflict might help u with the scenario

Comment: Honestly, I think you are better off accepting the asynchronous nature of AJAX programming, rather than force it into something that could yield unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the perfect situation for usint the [jQuery promise interface](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/).

You could declare an asynchronous operation, and specify what happens after it. I use it profusely in very complex interfaces that perform parallel calls, and works pretty well.

Cheers.